# context menu in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have dynamically populated a list in a Windows Forms application. Now I want to add a context menu such that when I select an item, the context menu will appear when I right click on the selected item, and not appear on right-click on other blank areas of form. I am currently using this code.

```vb
lv.Columns.Add("Button Text", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lv.Columns.Add("PID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lv.Columns.Add("Process Path", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
lv.Columns.Add("Hide Icon Permanently", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

Dim things As List(Of TrayButton) = TrayHelper.Tray.GetTrayButtons()
For Each b As TrayButton In things
    If b.Icon IsNot Nothing Then
        il.Images.Add(b.TrayIndex.ToString, b.Icon)
    Else
        ' When we can't find an icon, the listview will display this form's one.
        ' You could try to grab the icon from the process path I suppose. 
        il.Images.Add(b.TrayIndex.ToString, Me.Icon)
    End If
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(b.Text)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ProcessIdentifier.ToString)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ProcessPath)
    lvi.ImageKey = b.TrayIndex.ToString
    lv.Items.Add(lvi)

Next

Dim mnuContextMenu As New ContextMenu()
Me.ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu
Dim mnuItemHide As New MenuItem()
mnuItemHide.Text = "&Hide"

mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(mnuItemHide)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the ContextMenu to the **ListView** then...

Change:

```
Me.ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu
```

To:

```
lv.ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu
```

If it's not obvious, `Me` was changed to `lv`.

Comment: thanks for d response but it didn't work for me...i am still getting the context menu in blank area...

Comment: Do you have FullRowSelect() turned ON or OFF?

Comment: At any rate, you can use [ListView.Hittest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hittest.aspx) to determine where the click occurred.  With that information you can decide what to do with the ContextMenu.

Comment: FullRowSelect() is not working..giving an error...how ca i turn it own

Comment: Select the ListView, then set FullRowSelect() to True in the Properties Pane.  This won't fix your problem though.  It just makes it easier to write the code that uses HitTest() in the link I gave you previously.

Comment: i have done the listview thing by programming only....so there is no ListView in the properties

Comment: Ok...after you create the ListView: `lv.FullRowSelect = True`